About Gensim //Python
I don't know what happened. Two days ago, I could use it. When I use gensim to calculate TF-IDF, the procedure couldn't run.
Please help me solve this problem:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\86185\Desktop\SRT\where_is_null.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
  File "d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gensim import interfaces, utils
  File "d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gensim\interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils
  File "d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs, triu
ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' (d:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py)


Downvoting this question based on it's title. Write a title that summarizes the specific problem.

Did you try searching for an existing answer first, or review the "Similar Questions" that StackOverflow shows you before you submit your question?
Duplicate of (with workarounds there): ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' - Gensim

Sorry...This is the first time I've used this website, the question was solved, thanks your answer
